Which database is suitable to store LLM generated data?
I am developing a project where I give a transcript of a video to an LLM (I'm simply calling OpenAI's APIs). The LLM generates a wide range of data such as summaries, named entities (NER), etc. I want to store all the data in a database. I'm considering using a relational database and perhaps I'll need to pre-process the LLM-generated response to store in the tables (OR should I store the data as a JSON format?). Another option is a NoSQL database (eg. MongoDB) where I can dump the response as a document in collections. Can someone please guide me?

"of a video" - just one? Any database will be good enough. Even no database needed.

"a wide range of data" - what amount are we talking about? 10 kB, 100 MB, 40 GB, 1 TB? Producing 1 GB of data from an LLM will cost you ~800$, so the database might be least of a problem in this project.
